# Windows Live ID Authentication in ASP.Net Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, windows-live-id

I'm trying to implement Windows Live Authentication in my ASP.Net application. [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/17/integrate-windows-live-id-authentication-into-your-website.aspx) really help me out. Above article needs redirection to the Windows Live website for authentication which i don't want to be. As am writing the code in a web service which will be called from mobile application. Any idea on how i can achieve this ? Later with this authentication i will try to access the [Microsoft Forums Services](http://services.social.microsoft.com/ForumsServicePreview/ForumsService.svc).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `HttpWebRequest` class to post the credentials along with the AppId if you don't want to use this frame or you can't because of the service.

Comment: How can i post username and password to http://login.live.com/controls/WebAuth.htm?appid=123456   code example will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an appid at the moment, but you can create a page(just for testing purposes) and include the frame with the URL and use a sniffer to take a look at the Post (you could also see it with FireBug). I could help you out more in a couple of hours (I am at work right now) if you want to.